# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^x} = \prod_{p} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{f(p^i)}{p^{ix}}$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that if $f$ is a multiplicative number theoretic function, then
>   we have the formal identity
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^x}=\prod_{p}(1 +
>  \frac{f(p)}{p^x}+\frac{f(p^2)}{p^{2x}}+\frac{f(p^3)}{p^{3x}}+···)$$
>   $$=\prod_{p} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{f(p^i)}{p^{ix}}$$

Trying to find a pattern, I wrote out,

$$\frac{f(1)}{1^x}+\frac{f(2)}{2^x}+\frac{f(3)}{3^x}+\frac{f(4)}{4^x}+\frac{f
(5)}{5^x}+...$$

$$=(1+\frac{f(2)}{2^{x}}+\frac{f(2^2)}{2^{2x}}+\frac{f(2^3)}{2^{3x}}+...) \cdot(1+\frac{f(3)}{3^x}+\frac{f(3^2)}{3^{2x}}+\frac{f(3^3)}{3^{3x}}+...)\cdot$$

$$\cdot (1+\frac{f(5)}{5^x}+\frac{f(5^2)}{5^{2x}}+\frac{f(5^3)}{5^{3x}}+...)\cdot(1+\frac{f(7)}{7^x}+\frac{f(7^2)}{7^{2x}}+\frac{f(7^3)}{7^{3x}}+...).......$$

However, I fail to see one. If someone could guide me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Try showing that every term in the LHS is included in the RHS and also that every term in the RHS is included in the LHS.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of using FTA, but how would one even factorize the RHS since it's an infinite product of infinite sums?

Comment: If you think about how the terms in the RHS would look like after we expand the whole thing, then it's going to be a product of the form $\prod f(p^k)/p^{xk}$ where $k \geq 0$ for every $p$. And because $f$ is multiplicative, this is just going to be equal to $f(n)/n^x$ for $n = \prod p^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a general [Dirichlet Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series).
Consider when $f(n)=1$. Then you have the Zeta Function, which we know has an Euler Product Representation.

$$\prod_{p}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f(p^i)}{p^{ix}}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{f(p_{1}^i)}{p_{1}^{ix}}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{f(p_{2}^i)}{p_{2}^{ix}}...=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty...\frac{f(p_{1}^m)}{p_{1}^{mx}}\frac{f(p_{2}^k)}{p_{2}^{kx}}...$$

We know by the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) that any integer $n$ is composed of a product over the powers of primes. Also note that since $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function, $$f(p_{1}^m)f(p_{2}^k)...=f(p_{1}^mp_{2}^k...)$$ So we can still apply the fundamental theorem inside of the function.

The end result is your initial Dirichlet Series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^x}$$

Comment: And if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)n^{-s}|$ converges then 
$\lim_{k \to \infty} |\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s}-\prod_{p \le k} (1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(p^i) p^{-si})| $ $=\lim_{k \to \infty}|\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s} (1-1_{\text{Lpf}(n) \le k})| \le
\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n) n^{-s} | 1_{\text{Lpf}(n) > k} = 0$, where $\text{Lpf}(n)(n) = \sup_{p | n} p$.

Comment: And since every number can be expressed as a unique product of powers of primes, then each term in the LHS is only accounted for once. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, no integers can have the same prime product representation and each term in the expanded product has a unique combination of prime powers.